# want to decrease the size of the div which is added in dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am added div content into the dialog box using jquery.I am using the same div content to display in my page.Now i want to decrease the size of content by percentage which i am pushing in dialog.But it should apply only for the content of dialog not for the content on my page.So how can i do that using jquery?help me

```
$(function() {
        $( "#maincontainer" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width:50%,
            height:400,
            autoClose: false,
            show: "fold",
            hide: "core"
        });

        $( "#previewBtn").click(function() {
            $( "#maincontainer" ).dialog( "open" );
            return false;
        });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "decrease the size of content"? Truncate the string?

Comment: "decrease the size of content" means the view that can be seen in dialog must be smaller than what we see in normal web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you 'height:auto' property; this may work